# How can I import a XML file in a XSLT and parse it

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file which is automatically generated by system. I have a XSLT which transforms the XML into another XML format. In my input XML I have user ID's

I have another XML (static), users.xml, which contains all the user information.

I want to import  this users.xml into my XSLT and check the user id from input XML against this XMl. Is this possible?

I am using XSLT 1.0 and i am using `msxsl.exe` for transformation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use XSLT's `document` function to access an XML file other than the main one.